# Shell script for Converting a record to double quoted comma separated strings

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I want to write a shell script for following scenario.
I have a record

```
"apple""banana""pineapple"
```

And I would like each string to be in double quote, and comma separated, like this:

```
"apple","banana","pineapple"
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
sed 's/""/","/g'

 user@host:~$  echo '"apple""banana""pineapple"' | sed  's/""/","/g'
"apple","banana","pineapple"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir 
I just want to make the process dynamic.
Dynamic in a sense the number of columns in changing for each record line

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner should work for the given example:

```
awk -F'""' -v OFS='","' '$1=$1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir 
I just want to make the process dynamic.
Dynamic in a sense the number of columns in changing for each record line

Comment: That will fail if/when the first field is empty. Don't rely on `$1=$1` evaluating to a true condition unless you have a specific purpose in mind and understand the caveats - always use `{$1=$1}1` instead by default. @RohanShah - clarify your comment and edit your question to show a case where the current answers do not do what you want.

Comment: @Kent thanks your script works for most of the scenarios.
But if the field is empty i am facing an issue. So for example record is
"a""b""c""d""e"""
Then I get the output as
"a","b","c""d","e",","
And what expected is 
"a","b","c""d","e",""
Can you please help me for covering those scenario

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @RohanShah tested my command with your example in comment, it gives expected output. `"a","b","c","d","e",""`.

Comment: @Ed Morton Yes you are right the condition fails when the first field is empty.
Could you please help me on this.

Comment: @RohanShah Ed is right. `$1=$1` won't print output if you have empty or `0` in `$1`, I admit that I was lazy and only checked the given example. `{$1=$1}1` should work, as Ed said if you have empty `$1`